# FileStreamResult with mimeType audio/mpeg doesn't play stream when deployed to Azure

Tags: azure, audio-streaming, filestreamresult

There is an online radio published over HTTP and a custom port (e.g. http://44.44.44.44:56/stream/1) and I need to implement a proxy that exposes the same radio stream over HTTPS without a custom port (e.g. https://coolradio.azurewebsites.net/api/radio/AzureStream)

I have implemented a `dotnet 6` web API and it works when running locally:

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> AzureStream()
{
    var sourceUrl = "http://44.44.44.44:56/stream/1"
    var mimeType = "audio/mpeg";
    var client = new HttpClient();
    var sourceStream = await client.GetStreamAsync(sourceUrl);
    var fileStreamResult = new FileStreamResult(sourceStream, mimeType);
    return fileStreamResult;
}
```

[image]

When I publish this to Azure as a WebApp, I can access my other controllers and this one but instead of playing it just does nothing and the browser renders a slightly different picture, although the HTTP response, headers, and stream are identical:

[image]

I tried to avoid using HttpClient and instead downgrade to TcpClient but got the same result and with HttpClient (works locally, doesn't work when deployed to Azure):

```cs
var sourceUri = new Uri(sourceUrl); 
var sourceClient = new TcpClient();
string requestString = $"GET {sourceUri.PathAndQuery} HTTP/1.1\r\n"
                + $"Host: {sourceUri.Host}\r\n"
                + "Connection: keep-alive\r\n"
                + "\r\n";

await sourceClient.ConnectAsync(sourceUri.Host, sourceUri.Port);
var sourceStream = sourceClient.GetStream();
var writer = new StreamWriter(sourceStream);
writer.Write(requestString);
writer.Flush();

var fileStreamResult = new FileStreamResult(sourceStream, mimeType);
return fileStreamResult;
```

One important note, it used to work when I was on dotnetcore but once I switched to dotnet 6, it stopped (only the Azure part, locally works great).

How can I implement this proxy so I can publish it to Azure and expose the radio over HTTPS?

Comment: Can you post a link to the actual stream URL?

Comment: http://198.15.94.34:8006/1/

Comment: I mean, the one that isn't working.

Comment: https://radiovibes.azurewebsites.net/api/RadioVibes/stream/deephouse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Locally, you are accessing your application hosted in Kestrel. In Windows AppService, there is an additional layer running IIS.

In your case, IIS struggles with buffering the results of the stream your are passing. There are two solutions:

- Use Linux AppService plan
- Disable buffering

Full example:

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddScoped<MyCustomMiddleware>();
var app = builder.Build();
app.UseMiddleware<MyCustomMiddleware>();
app.MapGet("/audio/", async () =>
{
    var sourceUrl = "http://44.44.44.44:56/stream/1";
    var mimeType = "audio/mpeg";
    var client = new HttpClient();
    var sourceStream = await client.GetStreamAsync(sourceUrl);
    return Results.Stream(sourceStream, mimeType, enableRangeProcessing: false);
});

app.Run();

public class MyCustomMiddleware : IMiddleware
{
    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, RequestDelegate next)
    {
        var responseBodyFeature = context.Features.Get<IHttpResponseBodyFeature>();
        // Only required for Windows/IIS
        responseBodyFeature?.DisableBuffering();
        await next(context);
    }
}
```

You can remove the middleware if you are running on Linux. Your provided sample code using `HttpClient` failed for me with a `NotSupportedException`. So I used the other solution I usually use.

PS: I'm not sure if you can safely dispose `HttpClient` in this example. I added `using var client = new HttpClient();` and the application worked just fine, but I did not check it further.

Comment: I wasn't able to check if it works on linux (VS 4 Mac was missing an option to deploy to a newly created linux service plan web app), but I was able to created the middleware and disable buffering and it worked! Here is the live stream: https://radiovibes.azurewebsites.net/api/RadioVibes/stream/deephouse

Answer (score 1):

I can't speak to the Azure implementation side of things, so perhaps someone can give you a better answer there.  But, I can help you with this problem overall.

> When I publish this to Azure as a WebApp, I can access my other controllers and this one but instead of playing it just does nothing and the browser renders a slightly different picture, although the HTTP response, headers, and stream are identical:

That's not quite true.

The stream data being sent from your proxy stops after ~13 KB or so, which is why it can't be played.  You can see this with `curl -vvv`.

The source stream is a SHOUTcast server, which does not support chunked transfer encoding.  For legacy compatibility, almost none of these streaming servers do.  I suspect that the authors of the .NET 6 HttpClient are confused by the HTTP/1.0-style response where there is no `Content-Length` response header, but also no transfer encoding.  I suspect it's assuming chunked transfer.

If possible, your server could just handle the TLS side of the connection and proxy the HTTP request/response transparently, with no interpretation of HTTP at all.

If this is not possible with your stack, you could still make your own lightweight HTTP client, connect to the source stream, and then relay the stream data back to your clients.  That is, your server still receives HTTPS requests but the response data comes from a regular TCP socket connection.

Comment: I don't have access to the radio stream as this is a third-party stream so any change I have to do, I want to do it on the web app side (proxy). If HttpClient is confused by this kind of response from the source stream, shouldn't it break while running locally as well? I can run exactly the same code locally with no problem and the proxy plays/returns the stream great.

Comment: @Mando Hmmm, maybe in their infrastructure there is an extra layer for those HTTP requests?  As in, maybe they're transparently proxied before it even hits your app?  Either way, if you're able to make a socket connection you can test the theory and just see if you can get the response data before working up a more-tolerant HTTP client.

Comment: I tried to reimplement with HttpClient, works locally, doesn't work when deployed. Also it used to work (HttpClient) on older version of dotnet (dotnetcore) and now I upgraded to dotnet 6 when I start to see this issue.

Comment: @Mando You mean, you've made a regular TCP connection and you're able to get data back locally, but you make a regular TCP connection from Azure and you get... what?  If you're getting correct data from the server either way with a regular TCP connection, then the problem may very well be in the response side, which doesn't make any sense to me... surely the platform supports streaming HTTP responses?  Maybe not?

Comment: And I'm getting the same result as with HttpClient when Azure response stops the stream right after receiving the initial response (I posted the code on my original question). Azure should support the streaming, the code was working in previous dotnet versions (dotnetcore 2) but no longer works on dotnet 6 and only doesn't work when deployed to Azure.

Comment: @Mando Alright, so the issue is definitely somewhere in the response side.  I've never used this platform so maybe I can't be all that useful, but... I see there's an option on FileStreamResult for `EnableRangeProcessing`.  Can you ensure that's set to `false`?  The clients may make ranged requests, and we don't want something server-side to buffer to try to fulfill that request.

Comment: I tried just disabling the range processing and it didn't help but disabling buffering worked as suggested by @Alex IAT. Thanks for looking into it @Brat! Appreciate your time and effort and I was able to check many other options related to this streaming.

Comment: Awesome, glad there was a proper option to disable buffering!